# Why my setState returns an array, but the state is a promise when the component rerender?

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise, setstate

The code below try to check if an url is reachable or not.
The urls to check are stored in a state called *trackedUrls*
I update this state with an async function *checkAll*.
The object just before being updated seems fine, but when the component rerender, it contains a promise !

- Why ?
- What I should change to my code ?

```js
import React from "react"

export default function App() {

    const [trackedUrls, setTrackedUrls] = React.useState([])

    // 1st call, empty array, it's ok
    // 2nd call, useEffect populate trackedUrls with the correct value
    // 3rd call, when checkAll is called, it contains a Promise :/
    console.log("trackedUrls  :", trackedUrls)
    const wrappedUrls = trackedUrls.map(urlObject => {
        return (
            <div key={urlObject.id}>
                <a href={urlObject.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{urlObject.label}</a>
            </div>
        )
    })

    // check if the url is reachable
    // this works well if cors-anywhere is enable, click the button on the page
    async function checkUrl(url) {
        const corsUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + url
        const result = await fetch(corsUrl)
            .then(response => response.ok)
        console.log(result)
        return result
    }

    // Checks if every url in trackedUrls is reachable
    // I check simultaneously the urls with Promise.all
    async function checkAll() {
        setTrackedUrls(async oldTrackedUrls => {
            const newTrackedUrls = await Promise.all(oldTrackedUrls.map(async urlObject => {
                let isReachable = await checkUrl(urlObject.url)
                const newUrlObject = {
                    ...urlObject,
                    isReachable: isReachable
                }
                return newUrlObject
            }))

            // checkAll works quite well ! the object returned seems fine
            // (2) [{…}, {…}]
            // { id: '1', label: 'google', url: 'https://www.google.Fr', isReachable: true }
            // { id: '2', label: 'whatever', url: 'https://qmsjfqsmjfq.com', isReachable: false }
            console.log(newTrackedUrls)
            return newTrackedUrls
        })
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTrackedUrls([
            { id: "1", label: "google", url: "https://www.google.Fr" },
            { id: "2", label: "whatever", url: "https://qmsjfqsmjfq.com" }
        ])
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={checkAll}>Check all !</button>
            <div>
                {wrappedUrls}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This `setTrackedUrls(async oldTrackedUrls => {` sets a promise. The function passed to `setState` will set anything that the function returns as the value of the state. Your function is `async` so it returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad helped me to grasp the problem.
This works and it's less cumbersome.
If anyone has a solution with passing a function to setTrackedUrls, I'm interested just for educational purpose.

```js
    async function checkAll() {
        const newTrackedUrls = await Promise.all(trackedUrls.map(async urlObject => {
            let isReachable = await checkUrl(urlObject.url)
            const newUrlObject = {
                ...urlObject,
                isReachable: isReachable
            }
            return newUrlObject
        }))
        setTrackedUrls(newTrackedUrls)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only put data into setState.

Comment: What do you mean by your 2.?

Comment: const [bak, setBaka] = React.useState([]) = const [bak, setBaka] = useState([])

Comment: Well, it depends how you write your imports. It's perfectly fine to `import * as React from "react"` and then you need to use `React.useState`. Nothing wrong with that.